# How can i use a session for both clojure/script

Tags: session, clojure, clojurescript, ring

How can i use single session for both clojure and clojurescript.
For my login web application Server side i am using clojure and client side clojurescript.
And i need a session which is accessible from both client and server.
Is that possible?

Comment: You have to share it between the client and server, and the language does not matter here although it helps to have similar code (it would be the same in, say JavaScript and Node.js).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [example sente project](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente/tree/master/example-project) has a session which is accessible from both client and server. You will probably need to spend some time with it and mould it to your needs. But the example itself shows logging in and then a `:uid` inside `:session`, which is accessible from both the server and the client.

Comment: i have used sente in my project but i need to run my clj using ring handler ,so can i use sente with ring handler

Comment: That example project already uses ring for its server side routing `[ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"]`. Sente requires you to use certain middleware, but that won't get in the way. See `main-ring-handler`

Comment: Now my session works well.But iam trying to logout this session. How can i do that