# How to connect to MongoDB from a single page ClojureScript / React.js application using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, mongodb, reactjs, clojurescript

Consider a ClojureScript web application using reagent where the reagent components are subscribed to a single db atom containing a vector of maps. The contents of this vector is different for each user and has to be queried from a mongo database ( which is updated with regular intervals ). The database might be hosted by a third party. Considering that CongoMongo, Karras and Monger are Clojure ( not ClojureScript ) libraries what would be the best way to connect to MongoDB from a single page ClojureScript/React.js using Ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This “answer” is more of a comment but here goes.

If you don't absolutely need a Clojure backend, I'd recommend having a ClojureScript-only single-page app without any Clojure wrapper to Mongo (so no need for Sente either). As Timothy Baldridge (of Cognitect, so he knows a thing or two about this ) pointed out, your ClojureScript app can just make HTTP REST requests to the database.

[cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http) is a ClojureScript project that uses Clojure's `core.async` library to make HTTP requests and is perfect for interacting with REST APIs if you know or can learn `core.async`.

A more conventional (i.e., callbacks) approach, but still very ClojureScript-friendly, is to use Google Closure's [goog.net.XhrIo](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/xhrio#overview) library. I have an example [here of connecting to a public REST API](https://github.com/fasiha/zip-code-re-frame/blob/master/src/cljs/zip_code_reframe/handlers.cljs#L18-L26) using XhrIo and [re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame) (built on top of reagent, and highly recommended) that may help show how to get started.

Using either of these ClojureScript/JS libs, you can make requests directly from the ClojureScript browser app to the database, get replies, parse the JSON with `(js->clj (js/JSON.parse json-string))` or with [transit-cljs](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-cljs), and do something with the result.

Answer (score 2):

Since Mongo has a fairly simple REST interface (https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api), I'd be tempted to just write my own CLJS code that calls the Mongo server. Depends on your security requirements. But writing the CLJS code would be no different than any other remote request. Just a bit of string concatenation and parameter serialization.

Comment: This option is high on my list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **sente** to get communication going between the Reagent application and your web server. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173714/how-can-i-use-a-session-for-both-clojure-script/36174189#36174189) references an example client/server application that consists of a web server with browser access, giving you some buttons to press that return information from the server. It is not Reagent - but you can substitute what they use. It is a starting point example that works out of the box.

Then build up the example's web server so that it communicates with the three Clojure libraries rather than just returning static text as it does.

Comment: This solution would involve page reloads, right? These are definitely not an option, so I need access through Ajax. I might need to rework the question somewhat.

Comment: The example is Ajax or websockets (randomly chosen as it happens), so just make it use only Ajax if that is what you require.

Comment: The link jumps right into an example, I have a better perspective of the project a level higher. Looks promising will investigate.